# . . . have a natural talent for—thinks strongly and clearly

Tags: parsing, parenthesis

The following is from *Emma*, and I'm wondering whether there is a disconnection here; the preposition for seems to lack an object, and "thinks strongly and clearly" seems out of place, grammatically.

> No doubt he is a sensible man, and I suppose may have a natural talent **for**—**thinks strongly and clearly**—and when he takes a pen in hand, his thoughts naturally find proper words. It is so with some men. Yes, I understand the sort of mind. Vigorous, decided, with sentiments to a certain point, not coarse. A better written letter, Harriet (returning it,) than I had expected.”

Comment: What is "Emma"?

Answer (score -1):

> **No doubt he is a sensible man, and I suppose (he) may have a natural talent *for (he ) thinks strongly and clearly***.

I think now the sentence becomes grammatical.

I think **for** is a conjunction and the    subject **he** may have been deleted by mistake  or implied.

I think Emma is a novel.